# Facebook Mentions, Comments and Messages via Email

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-page

I was wondering if it's possible to receive emails from Facebook when someone:

- Mentions my FB page
- Comments on one of my FB page posts
- Messages to my FB page

Same with Instagram -which is connected to Meta Business-, can it be done for Instagram? so it emails me when someone:

- Messages me via Instagram
- Comments on one of my Instagram page posts
- Tags me on Instagram

I have been searching around and have been modifying Facebook settings, Meta Business settings, FB Pages Settings, and even tried with Zapier Automations with no luck so far, so I was wondering if maybe that Facebook feature isn't working anymore, if someone has managed to make it work or if there's any other way to do it? Maybe with the API or even an external service page?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated and my apologies if this is not the correct place to post this kind of question, I'm feeling so frustrated, somehow notifications via email for FB (even if the settings are available) don't seem to work for me.

Thank you!

---

P.S.: Btw, with Zapier it has been possible to receive messages sent to the page but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Facebook API do to that. There are application that do this (and usually forward them to other systems) but I'm not aware of anything free.

Currently, the verification is quite simplified. If you have basic knowledge of any programming language, it should be a weekend project for you.